# NanoFramework scan wifi networks in AP mode

Tags: c#, esp8266, esp32, esp8266wifi, nanoframework

I use nanoframefork & vs2019 to write firmware for my esp32 device.
version mscorelib 1.10.5 (my device does not support version higher)
The trouble is about to get the list of wifi networks, when device is in AP mode.
If use the code in example (https://github.com/nanoframework/Samples/blob/main/samples/Wifi/ScanWiFi/Program.cs):

```
WiFiAdapter wifi = WiFiAdapter.FindAllAdapters()[0];
```

the WiFiAdapter  wifi is NULL. It is null because there is no configured wifi interfaces (Wireless80211).
How can I scan wifi networks, when my ESP32 is in AP mode?

Comment: WiFiScan is the nutshell is for a station to search for an AP. Rule #1 for WiFi scan, the device must be in STA_MODE and be disconnected from any AP.

Answer (score 0):

There a sample showing how to scan networks [here](https://github.com/nanoframework/Samples/tree/main/samples/Wifi).

As for the device fw, you can update it to a newer version. Please use [nanoff tool](https://github.com/nanoframework/nanoFirmwareFlasher#esp32-usage-examples). You can find on the README examples and explanations on the options you should use to get it updated.

Comment: I'm in the same boat.  just downloaded nanoff, and with 'nanoff -target ESP32_WROOM_32 --update it loads 1.7.0.2, which provides mscorlib 1.10.5. Interestingly,  my recently purchased ESP32 reports in nanoff as ESP32-D0WDQ6 (revision 1).  Does that mean something?

Comment: That target name is obsolete. Please use `--platform esp32` and drop the target one. It will allow nanoff to choose the best fw based on your device capabilities. BTW, ESP32-D0WDQ6 it's the PN of the chip.